# Python -- Send Email When Exception Is Raised?

Tags: python, exception

I have a `python` class with many methods():

`Method1()`

`Method2()`

...........

...........

`MethodN()`

All methods -- while performing different tasks -- have the same scheme:

```
do something
do something else
has anything gone wrong?
    raise an exception
```

---

I want to be able to get an email whenever an exception is raised anywhere in the class.

Is there some easy way to combine this logic into the class, rather than calling `SendEmail()` before every `raise Exception` statement? what is the right, pythonic way to deal with such a case? canh a 'generalized' Exception handler be the solution? I'd be glad for any ideas you may have.

Comment: There are some exceptions that you don't need to catch, even in a global handler.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Note: Although this is a simple, obvious solution to the problem as stated, the [below answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6187851/577088) is probably better in most cases.**

If the alternative is this:

```
if problem_test():
    SendEmail()
    raise Exception
```

Then why don't you just define a custom `raise_email` method?

```
def raise_email(self, e):
    SendEmail()
    raise e
```

Answer (score 81):

like @User said before Python has [`logging.handlers.SMTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SMTPHandler) to send logged error message. Use logging module! Overriding exception class to send an email is a bad idea.

Quick example:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

smtp_handler = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=("smtp.example.com", 25),
                                            fromaddr="from@example.com", 
                                            toaddrs="to@example.com",
                                            subject=u"AppName error!")


logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(smtp_handler)

try:
  break
except Exception as e:
  logger.exception('Unhandled Exception')
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but I would change the last line to: logger.exception ('Unhandled Exception')

Comment: This does not work for me. I use gmail, so I changed mailhost to 'smtp.gmail.com', and the fromaddr and toaddrs to two gmail addresses. I do not receive any email.

Comment: @horaceT For gmail, change port from `25` to `587` and add parameter `credentials=(EMAIL, PASSWORD)` and `secure=()`. See below answer of @guneysus

Comment: When I run this I get `SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop`

Answer (score 8):

Python stdlib has dedicated class to do what you want. See `logging.handlers.SMTPHandler`

Answer (score 6):

[Gist Link](https://gist.github.com/guneysus/50d697c33d6fd631d03d)

The most important **trick** is here if secure parameter is not passed, the default value is **None** which raises exception if you are trying to authenticate with `TLS/SSL` enabled STMP Servers lik Gmail's, Yahoo's, Yandex's, STMP servers.

We passed an empty tuple to trigger `smtp.ehlo()` to authenticate correctly with SSL.

```
...
if self.secure is not None:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls(*self.secure)
    smtp.ehlo()
...


import logging
import logging.handlers

__author__ = 'Ahmed Şeref GÜNEYSU'


def foo():
    raise Exception("Foo Bar")


def main():
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(
        mailhost=("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 587),
        fromaddr="boss@example.com",
        toaddrs="me@example.com",
        subject="EXCEPTION",
        credentials=('smtpuser@example.com', 'MY SECRET PASSWORD'),
        secure=()))
    try:
        foo()
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5):

Beware [the wizard's apprentice](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XChxLGnIwCU)!

It would be better to log those errors, then check to see when the last email was sent, and if the timespan is too short, do not send another message because the human being will already be looking at the log file. For many things, one message per day would be enough, but even for system critical things, if you have already had one failure, what could go wrong if you wait two hours to send the next email?

If you send one email per two hour timespan, then the maximum number of emails per day is 12. And if you get a cascading failure (you will!) then it will most likely happen within a couple of hours of the first failure event.

Most large networking companies offer an SLA of 4 hour to fix a failure, measured from the time it first occurs (because cascading failures tend to repeat) until the customer is satisified that it is fixed. If you have a tighter SLA than that, then unless it is some finance industry service, you probably are offering too high of a service level.

But if you do have a 4 hour SLA, then I would make sure that any email sent within 2 - 4 hours of the last email, should use whatever bells and whistles you can to prioritise it, highlight it, etc. For instance use the X-Priority header and put the word URGENT in the subject so that your mail client can display it in large bold red letters.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        SendEmail()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
def mailexception(ex):
  # Be creative.
  print 'Mailing... NOW!'

def pokemontrainer(cls):
  class Rye(cls):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
      def catcher(func):
        def caller(*args, **kwargs):
          try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
          except Exception, e:
            mailexception(e)
            raise
        return caller
      ref = cls.__getattribute__(self, name)
      if hasattr(cls, name) and hasattr(getattr(cls, name), '__call__'):
        return catcher(ref)
  return Rye

@pokemontrainer
class Exceptor(object):
  def toss(self, e):
    raise e('Incoming salad!')

ex = Exceptor()
ex.toss(ValueError)
```

Comment: I got lost between 3 `defs` inside a `class` that is also inside a `def`. it might be that your solution is perfect, yet, is it a most to have such complexity?

Comment: It wraps the class in another class that checks to see if an attribute access is a method, and if so it wraps the method inside a function that catches any exception and sends an email in turn. It wraps them on the fly so that methods can be added later, instead of wrapping them when the class is built and missing any added after that.

Comment: By the way, you forgot to return the attribute when it's not a function. Right on the lines of “perils of unreadable code”

Answer (score 2):

By 2019, the easiest and best option seems to be [sentry](https://sentry.io/).

You need just two lines of code:

```
import sentry_sdk
sentry_sdk.init("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@sentry.io/xxxxxxx")
```

and it will send you a detailed email with any raised error.

After this you can further inspect the error on the Sentry website where there is impressive debug info - exceptions traceback, logs, data passed to functions, packages versions etc...

Comment: Is this an ad for a commercial package?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just [subclass `Exception`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions) and send the e-mail in the custom Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an except hook to send an email when an exception is not caught.

see [sys.excepthook](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook)

Answer (score 0):

You can use python alerting library. It supports email (via mailgun and sendgrid), telegram and slack notifications for sending alerts.

https://github.com/sinarezaei/alerting

Sample code:

```py
from alerting import Alerting
from alerting.clients import AlertingMailGunClient, AlertingSlackClient, AlertingTelegramClient

alerts = Alerting(
  clients=[
    AlertingMailGunClient(your_mailgun_api_key, your_domain, from_email, target_email),
    AlertingSlackClient(your_bot_user_oauth, target_channel),
    AlertingTelegramClient(bot_token, chat_id)
  ]
)


try:
  # something
except Exception as ex:
  alerting.send_alert(title='some bad error happened', message=str(ex))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answers that use the `logging` module, but I use the smtp library (`smtplib`) for this. To send error message, I do something like the following in the exception branch of the `try/except` block:

```
import smtplib as smtp

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
s.starttls()  
from_user = r"foo@gmail.com"
to_user = r"bar@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxxxxx"  
s.login(from_user, password)
subject = "Uh oh"
text = "XYZ error message you blew it!"
message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{text}"
s.sendmail(from_user, to_user, message);
```

This works well, but isn't the most secure option in the world. You actually have to tell google you want to let less secure apps connect (you can change this setting here: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps).