# How to send notification email when Exception Is Raised?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I have `try except` block inside `for loop`. If error happened I want to send an email saying "Error", if not, I need to send an email saying "Success".

**code example:**

```
    for file in files:
        try:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                # converting source variable to str because shutil has some bugs
                shutil.move(str(source) + "/" + file, dest_fs01 / current_year_folder / current_year_month_folder)
                break
        except Exception as e:
            error = str(e)
```

---

I tried something like this, but if there is no error, the variable `error` will not be existing

```
 for file in files:
        try:
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                # converting source variable to str because shutil has some bugs
                shutil.move(str(source) + "/" + file, dest_fs01 / current_year_folder / current_year_month_folder)
                break
        except Exception as e:
            error = str(e)
    
    if len(error) > 0:
        # sending email notifying about error
        message4 = """From: <from@email.com>
    To: <to@email.com>
    Subject: Error
    
                
                """ + error
        smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message4)
    
    
    else:
        # sending email notifying about successful completion
        message3 = """From: <from@email.com>
    To: <to@email.com>
    Subject: Success
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python -- Send Email When Exception Is Raised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182693/python-send-email-when-exception-is-raised)

Comment: I saw that but I am not that pro in python, so thought I'd find something simpler

Comment: Hi @Serdia did you find any answers, even i'm new to python my question is very similar to you question